# Complex logic in actions or reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In an app using React with Redux where should I handle the more complex logic (like generating ids or calculate some values)? In the action or in the reducer?

I could compute the values in the action and send them together with the action type to the reducer, or send a simpler action type and calculate them in the reducer.

Is there a best practice or some recommendation?

One advantage of computing them in the action would be to easier call other actions with the new computed values.